# JPanel addMouseListener() clean way

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm trying to find cleanest way to make clickable `JPanel`. Currently I accomplish it this way:

```java
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do something...
    }
});
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do this similarly to this:

```java
button.addActionListener(e -> doSomething());
```

and tried doing:

```java
panel.addMouseListener(e -> doSomething());
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: An Actionlistener is a functional interface: it declares one and only one method, but a MouseListener isn't. This is a requirement to be able to do this with a lambda

Comment: In this scenario, I actually prefer to use (private/protected) inner classes, as it isolates the functionality from the application flow - so you're need to trying to decode a methods execution amongst a bunch of event handlers - but that's me.  Also, "cleanest" is some what a personal concept